# Wie sagt man "When. Not if." auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice, phrase

For example, I say "If I'm ever successful.." and a response of encouragement would suggest that the only question is ***when*** I will be successful, rather than ***if*** I will be successful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*When, not if* - Relates to a temporal vs. a conditional case. You're trying to say "there's no way this can go wrong - It's just a matter of time until I'm successful."

The best way to literally translate this would be:

> "Wann". Nicht "ob".

or even as a nice alliteration

> "Wann". Nicht "wenn".

A less literal, but more common saying would be:

> Es ist nur eine Frage der Zeit, bis ...

Comment: Toll! Alles klar :)

Answer (score 2):

German has three main relevant conjunctions.

"Falls" is an explicitly conditional 'if'.

"Sobald" is an explicitly temporal 'when'.

"Wenn" can mean either and is about equally likely in either role.

Both "falls" and "sobald" are much less common than the all-rounder "wenn".

The problem with translating this phrasing is therefore that you'd probably have to replace "wenn" in one role with "wenn" in another role, which doesn't work to give the motivational aspect you want. Only if someone happened to have used "falls" you could reply with "sobald" to express what the English saying expresses. Usually, a German conversation must find other ways to convey this particular point.

Comment: OK I think I understand. How would you encourage a friend who says "Wenn ich eines Tages erfolgreich bin" ?

Comment: *Sobald! Nicht "wenn"!*

Answer (score 2):

I'd say "wenn, nicht falls" to express that it is out of question you'll some day be successful.

In general I'd follow this rule: If you can replace *if* by *whether*, use the German *ob*. If you can not, use *falls* or *wenn*. *When* can be translated as *wenn* if used in a conditional context or *wann* if used in a temporal context.

Examples:

> I wonder if (whether) he will be on time.
> Ich frage mich, ob er pünktlich sein wird.
>
> I'd be happy if you could help me.
> Ich wäre froh, wenn/falls Du mir helfen könntest.
>
> I wonder when he will arrive.
> Ich frage mich, wann er ankommt.
>
> I'll pick you up when you arrive.
> Ich hole Dich ab, wenn Du ankommst.

Comment: *Wenn* bedeutet das gleiche wie *falls*. *Wann, nicht wenn* wäre richtig.

Comment: @userunknown: Das ist so nicht richtig. "wenn" kann eben dasselbe wie "falls" bedeuten, oder statt dessen rein zeitlich gemeint sein. Auf einen Satz wie "Ich melde mich, falls wir fertig werden." ergäbe die Antwort "wann, nicht wenn" bzw. "wann, nicht falls" keinen Sinn, da "wann" sich in den Satz überhaupt nicht grammatikalisch korrekt einfügen ließe (oder zumindest nicht, ohne die Bedeutung in eine andere Richtung zu lenken).

Comment: Ja, das wäre dann "sobald". Wenn ist mitnichten rein zeitlich, sondern von einer Bedingung abhängig. Die Bedingung müsste schon rein zeitlich sein "wenn es 17 Uhr 30 ist", um rein zeitlich zu sein. Dagegen ist "Wenn der Mond untergegangen ist" davon abhängig, dass er auch wirklich untergeht. Das ist aber der Knackpunkt der Floskel, dass der, der sie verwendet, die Möglichkeit, dass das Ereignis nicht eintritt, paradigmatisch leugnen will. Ob das Ereignis eintritt steht gar nicht mehr zur Disposition, sondern nur wann.